# Getting rweibull to output n observations in (1,52) given specific shape, scale parameters

Tags: r, weibull-distribution

I was told the following will generate 52 observations in range (1,52), with a shape parameter of .5 and a scale parameter of 2.

Yet, there is a 67 so that is perhaps wrong?
What I need is N observations in range (1,52) with the observations conforming to a Weibull distribution with specific parameters.

```
> print(rweibull(52,.5,2))

 [1]  0.406647225  0.052710518  2.158733355  0.500174364  2.074537224    
 [6]  0.378695917  0.396309715  0.131268753  4.182770394  0.293154663    
[11]  2.045214882  0.016280681  0.268003469 17.612960070  2.375416850    
[16]  6.482297632  0.151320479  0.214247990  2.613026032  3.397453127    
[21]  7.357103077  2.054468323  3.090147233  2.594981565 21.316501285    
[26] 35.364512001  2.272848255  1.186967955  4.178822565  0.006659194    
[31]  6.006123713 ***67.918717193***  0.051010700  0.706372359  2.419090546    
[36]  1.858408184  9.545857635  2.182673324  0.892914986  0.244567333    
[41]  0.065993717  0.225678795 27.655436513  2.965634299  1.294741473    
[46]  0.069503896  1.266168448  3.949787345  3.391448817  1.663533337    
[51]  0.604392557  1.232525921
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit**: I apparently have solved my own question. The following will give me the expected # of failures in the T<sup>th</sup> month, given k as the shape, and 100 initial # of parts:

```
ceiling((pweibull(t,shape=k,scale=12)-pweibull(t-1,shape=k,scale=12))*100)
```

Comment: The Weibull is defined for non-negative argument, so there are no guarantees that finite samples will be returned only in the interval you specify. In any case what particular samples look like is, literally, "the luck of the draw" within the definition used for a distribution. You have to choose what to sacrifice. If you believe your variable is bounded as you state, the Weibull is a poor model. Perhaps you should explain why the [1, 52] interval should be honoured. Wanting a model that mimics idiosyncratic details of present data is, for example, usually an unsound idea.

Comment: Re the edit: because you haven't asked a question about failures, months, or parts, and the edit does not impose any restriction to the range $[1,52],$ it seems devoid of all but the most tenuous connection to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

> What I need is N observations in range (1,52) with the observations conforming to a Weibull distribution with specific parameters

The very statement of this problem ensures that you cannot satisfy these assumptions. You could fabricate some distribution that has a finite number of equal moments, looking "roughly Weibull", but the support of Weibull is all positive reals. That means there is always a non-zero probability of sampling a Weibull observation above any positive real constant, $c$.